# What is the most compact way of aliasing a Response type?

Tags: c#, c#-10.0

**.Net 6, c# 10 **and** .Net 7, c#11 or higher**

This question is not only about aliases. It's broader.

Scenario :

```
public class Item {
    public int x { get; set;}
}

public interface IMyController {
    public Task<IEnumerable<Item>> GetItems();
}

public class MyController {

     public async Task<IEnumerable<Item>> GetItems() {
          return new List<Item>() { ... };
     }
}
```

It's a common scenario to want to expose an API's interface (in this case, IMycontroller)

However I'm annoyed that the return type is a complex type (enumerale of something). I want the interface to be air-tight and **not leave anything to the end-user.** I'd like a GetItemsReponse type.

**Typescript** libraries such as **GraphQL** do it like this :

```
export interface Item { ... }
export type Items = Item[];
export type GetItemsResponse = Items;
```

**Problem :**

In C# there's no on-demand universal aliasing of types.

**Solution #1 : local alias in file.**

***IMyController.cs***

```
using GetItemsResponse = IEnumerable<Item>;

public interface IMyController {
    public Task<GetItemsResponse> GetItems();
}
```

Not fully satisfactory because the end-user has to do the same in **their** own code :

```
using GetItemsResponse = IEnumerable<Item>;
```

**Solution #2: global alias**

```
global using GetItemsResponse = IEnumerable<Item>;
```

That's a good solution for most people but for me it's a problem because I have **several types called "GetItemsResponse"** -- that's because I use **versioned** APIs. I don't want the names to start colliding globally.

```
global using GetItemsResponse = IEnumerable<ItemV1>;
global using GetItemsResponse = IEnumerable<ItemV2>; // uh oh, same name!

namespace My.API.v1 {
    public interface IMyController {
        public Task<IEnumerable<ItemV1>> GetItems(); // I want it to return GetItemsResponse 
    }
}

namespace My.API.v2 {
    public interface IMyController {
        public Task<IEnumerable<ItemV2>> GetItems(); I want it to return GetItemsResponse 
    }
}
```

**Solution #3 : Inherited type**

```
public class GetItemsResponse : List<Item> {
    ...
}
```

Not great because now I have to re-implement many of the underlying methods of `List`, starting with the constructor(s).

**CONCLUSION:**

Is there an elegant and compact way that I'm overlooking in modern C#? Focus on C#11 or higher first, C#10 comes last.

Comment: I don't follow exactly what you're trying to do. Are you sure that you're not over thinking some issue? What is it with a response type of `IEnumerable<Item>` that you don't like?

Comment: See the section showing how GraphQL does it. I really want it unbreakable. If I decide to change from IEnumerable to IReadOnlyList, for example, then the end-user might not notice a breaking change. Just like GraphQL and other libs, I want the Response to be called "Response", full stop, in every circumstance.